# Changing proxy_cache_valid value based on GET Query

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm currently trying to setup a nginx cache that should cache a location for a long time but if query parameters are present for only a few minutes.

So basically:

```
http://example.com/mypath -> long cache
http://example.com/mypath?param=1 -> short cache
```

My current config looks something like this:

```
location "~^(/mypath)"
{
        proxy_cache        example.com_my_cache_http;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 15m;
        ...
}
```

I can't use diffrent locations because locations can't match query parameters,
I have tried using an **if** (I know it's bad practice)

```
if ($args ~ param) {
            proxy_cache        example.com_my_cache_http;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 15m;
} else {
            proxy_cache        example.com_my_cache_http;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 2d;
}
```

This results in:

```
Testing nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "proxy_cache" directive is not allowed here
```

I also tried using variables:

```
    set $time "1h";

    if ($args ~ param) {
        set $time "2m";
    }

    proxy_cache        example.com_my_cache_http;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 $time;
```

This results in:

```
Testing nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] invalid time value "$time"
```

I'm really running out of ideas any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: You backend could send `X-Accel-Expires` header. Also, probably you just need to bypass cache?

Comment: Hi,bypassing is not an option as I still need a short cash to catch users that spam hit F5.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use a `map`.

```
map $arg_param $cache_valid_404 {
    ""      2d;
    1       15m;
}
```

Then you set:

```
proxy_cache_valid 404 $cache_valid_404;
```

Comment: where can I put the "map" ? I'm getting map directive not allowed here if I define it inside or outside of the location

Comment: @gries `map` goes under `http` only. It should not be in any other place.

Comment: It doesn't work. 'nginx: [emerg] invalid time value "$cache_valid_404" in /path...'